# Assign data scraped from a website to tuples

Tags: python, selenium

Working on a project to compare league champion winrates from op.gg and I cant find a way to actually assign the winrate to a champions name instead of just printing them independently side by side. I think tuples are my best bet for this but im not 100% if that is correct or how to turn this print statement into tuples.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get('https://na.op.gg/statistics/champion/')

rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="ChampionStatsTable"]//tr[./td]')
data = []
for row in rows:
    name = row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[@class="Cell ChampionName"]').text
    win_rate = row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[@class="Cell ChampionName"]/following-sibling::td[1]').text
    print(name + ': ' + win_rate)
```

Comment: Seems like a great use for a dictionary; `my_dict[name]=win_rate` or similar

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

To store the values in the list as tuples, just substitute the print:

```
print(name + ': ' + win_rate)
```

, with the assignment:

```
data.append((name, win_rate))
```

Then you can access them by indices:

```
print(data[3][0])   # will print the 4th element's name
print(data[1][1])   # will print the 2nd element's win_rate
```

If the names are unique, you may want to use a dictionary instead - then you can get the win_rate by a known name:

```
dict_data = {}
for row in rows:
    # and inside the for loop
    dict_data[name] = win_rate

print(dict_data['winner X'])   # will print that name's win_rate

for name in dict_data:    # to iterate over all names:
     print('the name: {}'.format(name)) 
     print('the win_rate: {}'.format(dict_data[name]))
```